# How can I see the contents of the Memcachier cache on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, memcached, dalli, memcachier

I need to inspect the cache, and see what IP's are blocked*, and for how long.

NB: I am on a developer/free plan.

Update:

- I'm using the rack-throttle gem which stores blocked IP's in the cache.

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the Memcachier add-on name in your Heroku control panel you are redirected to the Memcachier dashboard for the instance. More details are available in the [add-on documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/advanced-memcache#list-management).

The dashboard will provide you some information such as limits, memory consumption and items in the collection.

However, keep in mind that Memcached itself [doesn't provide advanced commands](http://lzone.de/dump+memcache+keys) to list all keys in the database.

As far as I know, there is no IP blocking feature in Memcachier.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the dashboard, but I need to inspect the key-value-pairs themselves. Do you know how to do that on HerokU?

Comment: As I said, the Memcached protocol doesn't provide such feature. Please read the article I linked.

Answer (score 1):

I donot know whether this will help you: https://gist.github.com/bkimble/1365005

I change a little in my apps to get the keys. we should not use it frequently.

Comment: Awesome! This would solve the problem locally, I presume. I need a version for Heroku though.

Comment: This isn't going to work for MemCachier since (a) the binary protocol is required for authentication, and this gist uses the ascii protocol, and (b) MemCachier doesn't support the stats sub commands to list all keys.